# Alguns plugins não funcionam com versões jQuery diferentes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Me perdoem se esta pergunta parecer um pouco ignorante, mas uma coisa que eu percebi enquanto testava alguns plugins era que alguns, antigos ou não, não funcionavam com uma versão do Jquery especifica. por padrão estava usando a versão [3.1](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js), e como é/era a mais atualizada pensava que todos os plugins, sendo antigos ou não, iriam funcionar, porém vi que alguns só funcionavam com a versão **1.10** e etc, por que isso ocorre? o qual a melhor forma de contornar isso?

Comment: acima versão 3 são beta, utilize 1.9.1 ou 2.1.1 mais usado!

Comment: Quais plugins estão dando problema?

Comment: A versão "estável" é a 1.9.1. Entre aspas pois é a que teve maior número de `deprecated` das outras versões e a mais usada para base com outros frameworks

Comment: Você conseguiu uma resposta para sua pergunta?

Comment: SIm, a do KingRider foi útil.